# Create a simple vertical line on gantt chart from react-google-charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, gantt-chart, react-google-charts

I want to create a vertical red line on the current date on my gantt chart in react.
See the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/tree/master/sandboxes/gantt/grouping?file=%2FApp.tsx%3A3%2C1).
Additionally, I'd like to get all completed tasks and partial fills to be dark grey.
I wasn't successful with the options they provide in [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#configuration-options).